# Visibility Graph algorithm applications in time series

Tags: graph, visibility

I am looking for Visibility Graph applications. In line with the articles I read, I have obtained the applications of this algorithm, which are as follows:

1. Robot path planning
2. Placement of radio antennas
3. Complex network theory
4. Regional planning

This algorithm is also used to analyse time series. In the analysis of time series using the graph algorithm, the question arose that after obtaining the graph obtained from this algorithm: what is the efficiency of this graph?

If we consider the meteorological data and obtain its graph with the Visibility Graph Algorithm, from this graph we can obtain statistical properties or the degree distribution of networks that follow the law of power.

In general, my question is what efficiency and information does the graph from the meteorological time series or the purchase of medicine at certain times and many other time series provide us with?

Comment: This looks an *information/data science* question rather than a programming one.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the paper entitled [From time series to complex networks: The visibility graph](https://www.pnas.org/content/105/13/4972) by Lucas Lacasa, Bartolo Luque, Fernando Ballesteros, Jordi Luque, and Juan Carlos Nuño, in 2018, the visibility graph of a time series if invariant under translation, rescaling, addition of a linear trend, and other transformations. It however captures key time series features, like periodicity, self-similar indexes, etc.